# iphone post to google fusion table without login

Tags: iphone, oauth, google-fusion-tables

I need my iphone app to allow users to post to a google fusion table without entering a username and password.  currently I use google client login with the password hard coded into the app. Obviously this is a poor solution, but I cannot find how to do this with oauth?

Comment: check out [this](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) Google Fusion Tables API link, may help you

Comment: yes, I have spent many hours looking through the api documentation, but I cannot figure out how to have the iphone app login automatically.

Comment: It looks like service accounts may do want I want, but I don't think this is supported in the iOS oauth sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the user to be submitting data to their own individual fusion tables, or all users to be modifying a single table that you own?

For the first case, you'll want the user to authorize (via oauth) access to their account (there's no iOS specific client library from Google, but there are a number of answers here in SO about how to do this)

If you want everyone to be entering data into the same table, the best practice is probably not to hardcode the password and/or tokens into your app, but rather to use a proxy (for example via a service account running on AppEngine).  Note that this proxy should still do some kind of authentication with your iphone users so random folks can't just easily post whatever they want to it w/o running your app.